# The same to you or likewise

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Imagine when it comes to say goodbye, someone says:

-Have a good day.

In order to indicate the message: "the same to you", would it sound idiomatic to answer

-Likewise.

The word "Likewise" is an adverb here; but the question is that whether it can work as a sentence independently or one has to complete it with the resting part; e.g.

- Likewise, I wish the same to you...

Or something like that!

Answer (score 1):

> Have a good day!

Usually, the phrase is

> Have a nice/great day!

and it may be responded with "Thank you!", "(The)Same to you!", "And you!", and "You too!" [(which seems to be the most frequent response)](https://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/887469-how-do-YOU-respond-to-quot-have-a-good-day-quot).

To sound more polite, you may add "Thanks/thank you" to whatever response:

> Have a nice day!
>
> Thanks, you too!

As for the "likewise" response, I think it might work too; although the "I wish the same to you" part seems to be redundant.

Comment: Isn't it **Thanks! You too.** not **Thanks, you too!**?